# static link mapi32.lib with my vc++ project in vs.net2005

Tags: visual-c++

I want to static link mapi32.lib with my vc++ project in vs.net2005 project. I am using the following import statement inside my testdll.cpp project which is my entry point of the application.

```
#import "mapi32.lib"
```

I have put references for C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\Lib path inside c/c++ -> general section and Linker->general section of the project.And also add reference in properties -> debug source files section as well.

But after doing all this I am getting the following error, please help

> Error 3 fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   type library file: 'c:\program
>   files\microsoft visual studio
>   8\vc\platformsdk\lib\mapi32.lib':
>   Error loading type library/DLL.
>   c:\TestDll\TestDll\TestDll\TestDll.cpp
>   14

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To statically link with `mapi.lib`, you need to tell the **linker** about it. The best way to do this is in your project settings. Go to ***Linker -> Input*** and add the `mapi32.lib` to the ***Additional Dependencies*** field. You sould do this step for all your project configurations.

To refer to the lib within your code, of course you have to include the appropriate header files.

The `#import "mapi32.lib"` statement is usually used to import COM object type libraries and has nothing to do with static linking. So you should remove that line.

Good luck.